# Joda time - get next time it's X o'clock

Tags: java, time, jodatime, java-time, localdatetime

I need to get the next datetime when it's say, 20.00 o'clock.

So for instance, if it's 13.00 hours, it'd give me the datetime corresponding to today at 20.00.

But if it's 21.00, it'd give me tomorrow at 20.00.

How can I achieve this? Is there some built in function that I just can't find the name of?

In a pinch I could also use Java Time instead of Joda Time.

Comment: What have you tried? If nothing, why not?

Comment: Try to convert your description to code. What would that look like?

Comment: 1) var time = current time 2) **if** time is after desiredTime **then** time = time + 1 day **else** do nothing 3) time = time.atTime(desiredTime)

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash It seems perfectly reasonable request. Why do you care about the context? User sets an alarm for 8AM. If they do it at 9AM it needs to go off tomorrow. If they do it at 7AM, it needs to go off in 1 hour. I just made this example up but you get the point.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I'm not sure if it was you that closed the question but I'm not sure I understand why it's not "focused" enough - I think it's pretty focused. A stupid question maybe

Comment: @rutchkiwi - No, I didn't close the question. I 100% agree with you that there is no reason why this question should be closed with the reason, "This question needs to be more focused." The question is focused on a single problem and also clear enough.

Answer (score 4):

Add one day to `DateTime` if the time is past 20:00.

**Demo:**

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;

public final class Main {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getNextTime("13.00"));
        System.out.println(getNextTime("21.00"));
    }

    static DateTime getNextTime(String strTime) {
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(strTime);
        DateTime dt = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).withTime(new LocalTime(20, 0));

        if (time.isAfter(new LocalTime(20, 0))) {
            dt = dt.plusDays(1);
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-03-29T20:00:00.000+01:00
2021-03-30T20:00:00.000+01:00
```

**Note:** Check the following notice at the [Home Page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

> Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java
> prior to Java SE 8. Users are now asked to migrate to java.time
> (JSR-310).

**Using the modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public final class Main {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getNextTime("13.00"));
        System.out.println(getNextTime("21.00"));
    }

    static ZonedDateTime getNextTime(String strTime) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH.mm");
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(strTime, dtf);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).withHour(20);

        if (time.isAfter(LocalTime.of(20, 0))) {
            zdt = zdt.plusDays(1);
        }
        return zdt;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-03-29T20:00:18.325419+01:00[Europe/London]
2021-03-30T20:00:18.327587+01:00[Europe/London]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but did you even look at your own output. It's wrong!

Comment: @Andreas - Can you please let me know what wrong do you see with the answer?

Comment: Next 13:00 is support to be tomorrow 3/30 at 13:00, and next 20.00 is supposed to be today 3/29 at 20:00. None of the 4 outputs are correct.

Comment: @Andreas - All the output are correct as per the requirement. Please go through the question once again. I've no problem editing my answer if what you say is correct.

Comment: Ok, sorry, the code is confusing. The "inputs" to the method would be "current date/time" and "target time", right? Sure, some of those "inputs" could be "hardcoded" inside the method, but for full reusability, those are the "variables" the method has to work with. So you passing in the "current time", without "current date", and hardcoding "target time", is just plain confusing.

Comment: More than likely, in real code, not an example of 20:00 as given in the question, the target time would not be hardcoded like that, but given by configuration, so would definitely be a parameter to the method. In real code, the current date/time would be obtained by calling `now()`, or given as a parameter if you want the method to be unit-testable, with perhaps an overload that calls `now()` for you.

Comment: But, you're right, I misunderstood the parameter (bad parameter name didn't identify meaning, i.e,. whether "current" or "target" time), so I have removed my down-vote.